# How to do nested searching in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a newbie on mongodb. Working on a portal I want to implement a search, which is nested. My data is as below:

```
"SubjectValuation": [
    {
      "Subject": "Mathematics",
      "Primary": "6.5",
      "KeyStage3": "7",
      "GCSE": "7.5",
      "Alevel": "7.5",
      "University": "6.5"
    },
    {
      "Subject": "English",
      "Primary": "6.5",
      "KeyStage3": "7.5",
      "GCSE": "7.5",
      "Alevel": "8",
      "University": "-"
    },
```

The query I ran was:

```
$query = $mongoDb->find(array('City' => $city,  'SubjectValuation.Subject' => $subject, 'SubjectValuation.Primary' => $level));
```

When I pass 'Mathematics' in `$subject` I get a result, but when I pass 'English' then no record gets retrieved. How do I implement nested search for this kind of array?

Answer (score 0):

try this one not  tested but logically it  work
$query = $mongoDb->find(array('City' => $city, '$and'=>['SubjectValuation.Subject' => $subject, 'SubjectValuation.Primary' => $level ]));

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working giving error kind of bad $and